# List of supported attribute keys for NSString.sizeWithAttributes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

iOS 7 uses `NSString::sizeWithAttributes` to calculate the size of the bounding box of an `NSString` given an `NSDictionary` of attributes. However, I can't find a resource that lists all the enumerated keys available for use in that `NSDictionary`.

The [NSString UIKit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes%3a) says that

> These are the same attributes that can be applied to an NSAttributedString object

but doesn't list them, and they're not listed in the [`NSAttributedString` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) either.

Also: of the available attribute keys, which are the most fundamental to sizing a multiline label? It seems that font size and line break mode are the most important, but without a list of the available options it's hard to say...

Answer (score 16):

I search for 20 minutes and then find the answer immediately *after* posting on SO. Sigh.

For future reference, the available attributes are listed toward the bottom of the [NSAttributedString - Foundation Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring), in the [Character Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1652619-character_attributes) section.

Comment: These links are now 404!, try https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key

Answer (score 9):

Above link is dead. [Here is the new one](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1652619-character_attributes).

```
let NSAttachmentAttributeName: String
let NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: String
let NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: String
let NSCursorAttributeName: String
let NSExpansionAttributeName: String
let NSFontAttributeName: String
let NSForegroundColorAttributeName: String
let NSKernAttributeName: String
let NSLigatureAttributeName: String
let NSLinkAttributeName: String
let NSMarkedClauseSegmentAttributeName: String
let NSObliquenessAttributeName: String
let NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: String
let NSShadowAttributeName: String
let NSSpellingStateAttributeName: String
let NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName: String
let NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: String
let NSStrokeColorAttributeName: String
let NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: String
let NSSuperscriptAttributeName: String
let NSTextAlternativesAttributeName: String
let NSTextEffectAttributeName: String
let NSToolTipAttributeName: String
let NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: String
let NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: String
let NSVerticalGlyphFormAttributeName: String
let NSWritingDirectionAttributeName: String
```

Comment: That's not Objective-C.

Comment: @Droppy yes but attributes names don't relate to language don't you think?

Comment: It depends how you compare them.

Comment: This link is now dead also. :(

Comment: Apple documentation is ridiculous. After searching for 1 hour I still haven't found an official documentation for all attributes

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key lists them all. [I was hoping to copy an actual list somewhere] (This is the NSAttributedString.Key/NSAttributedStringKey page in the documentation)