# What are the supported attributes for UINavigationBar.titleTextAttributes?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, uiappearance

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624953-titletextattributes#) it refers to the "NSString UIKit Additions Reference" for the list of supported attributes, but I cannot find any such document in the Apple API Reference.

I am trying to use the UIAppearance proxy to set the default text color for a navigation item title: `UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes`

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported attributes is now found toward the bottom of the [NSAttributedString - Foundation Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring), in the [Character Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1652619-character_attributes) section.

(Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599108) about `NSString.sizeWithAttributes()` for putting me on the right trail! I wanted to document it under this question for people looking for UIAppearance help.)